# How to pass external resouce yml /property file while running spark job on cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, databricks, spark-submit

I am using spark-sql 2.4.1 version, jackson jars & Java 8.

In my spark program/job I am reading few configurations/properties from external "conditions.yml" file which is place in "resource" folder of my Java Project as below

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        try {
            driverConfig = mapper.readValue(
                    Configuration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("conditions.yml"),Configuration.class);

        }
```

If I want to pass "conditions.yml" file from outside while submitting spark-job how to pass this file ? where it should be placed?

In my program I am reading from "resouces" directory i.e. .getResourceAsStream("conditions.yml")  ...if i pass this property file from spark-submit ...will the job takes from here from resouces or external path ?

If I want to pass as external file , do I need to change the code above ?

> **Updated Question:**

In my spark driver program I am reading the property file as program arguments 
Which is being loaded as below

```
 Config props = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(args[0]));
```

While running my spark job in shell script
I am giving as below

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name MyDriver  \
--jars "/local/jars/*.jar" \
--files hdfs://files/application-cloud-dev.properties,hdfs://files/condition.yml \
--class com.sp.MyDriver \
--executor-cores 3 \
--executor-memory 9g \
--num-executors 5 \
--driver-cores 2 \
--driver-memory 4g \
--driver-java-options -Dconfig.file=./application-cloud-dev.properties \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=./application-cloud-dev.properties \
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=. \
--driver-class-path . \
 ca-datamigration-0.0.1.jar application-cloud-dev.properties condition.yml
```

> Error :

Not loading the properties... what is wrong here ? What is the correct way to pass the Program Args to Spark-Job Java program?

Answer (score 2):

you will have to use --file path to your file  in spark-submit command to be able to pass any files.  please note this is

syntax for that is

```
 "--file /home/user/config/my-file.yml"
```

if it is on hdfs then provide the hdfs path

this should copy the file to class path and your code should be able find it from the driver.

the implementation of reading the file should be done with something like this

```
def readProperties(propertiesPath: String) = {

val url = getClass.getResource("/" + propertiesPath)
assert(url != null, s"Could not create URL to read $propertiesPath properties file")
val source = Source.fromURL(url)
val properties = new Properties
properties.load(source.bufferedReader)

properties
}
```

hope that is what you are looking for

Comment: thank you , right now i am hardcoding in the code right , to read from resources folder , If I give some other path using --file , how the driver understand it should take this file from --file  instead of what is mentioned in the code resource file path ?

Comment: when you provide it with file option.. spark will copy that to classpath.. in your code you should just read it as /yourfilename.yml

Answer (score 0):

You can add:
spec:
args:

- `--deploy-mode`
- `cluster`

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.